# Can basic field theory be transposed over to group theory? (polynomials in a group-only setting)

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Polynomials over a non-abelian group might look like $f(x) = x^7ax^3bxc$.  Directly moving from field to group, we would define the usual degree as the sum of the exponents of the variable $x$.

*Digression*: This might be useful for the analogy, but if you wanted to compute (using a machine) the value a large polynomial in a group, you would probably want to get rid of exponential notation and use only the group law and grouping $(\cdot)$, e.g. $f(x) = (x\cdot x)^3x a x^3 b xc$, where for economy of notation we allow exponents only up to $3$, as this will still directly given a recipe for a computer to follow that is minimal in number of group operations.

So let's keep degree analogous to field theory of polynomials.

Clearly, for some $f(x)$, the equation $f(x) = 1$ has a solution, and in other cases it does not, just as in field theory.  Anyone try this?  Intuitively, it seems like it would have far reaching applications since the theory of field extensions does.

Please comment, or give a reason why this is fruitless.  I don't care if nobody now cares about this, nor do I have time to explore in depth every idea, since no one is paying me to, and I eat food and have to buy things to survive.

Comment: Without field structure we do not have many of the fruitful properties such as PID, UFD, Noetherian, division algorithm, nice theory of extensions... I'd also like to add that the 'polynomial' group you've defined is just the free product of the group $G$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ representing the indeterminants. I don't know much about this construction so maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: @basket Thanks for the comment.  Sounds fruitless then.  But you didn't mention anything about minimal polynomials which was sort of my current approach to it.  I am most interested in minimal group presentations, if there is even a definition for that.  The presentations being made up of a list of polynomial equations.

Comment: The minimal polynomial relies on the fact that $k[x] = k \bigotimes \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a PID. I *really* doubt it exists in this case.

Comment: @basket you mean 'exists in general'?   As clearly in $G = (\Bbb{Z}/(3))^{\times}$, $\min(2, x) = x^2$.  I mean, if we create required filters like 'monic', etc.  Otherwise it might also be $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: I would call that a monomial, and cannot see how without addition you can get anything else. The analogy is pretty bad.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen you're nitpicking.  Obviously I can't pick the name any how.  And you gave no mathematical reasoning that I can understand, why the analogy is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the category of groups $\mathbb{Z}$ has the nice property that for any $H$ and $h \in H$ there is a unique morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to H, 1 \mapsto h$. As the coproduct of $G$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ the generalized polynomial group satisfies the property that for any $G \to H$ and $h \in H$ there is a unique $G[x] \to H$ such that $x \mapsto h$ and $G \to G[x] \to H$ commutes. So it actually satisfies the same universal property that $A \to A[x]$ does in the category of rings. However this is where the similarity abruptly starts to end.

For an inclusion $G \hookrightarrow H$ we do have some notion of minimality, namely the least 'degree' of a polynomial over $G$ such that $h$ is a root. Unfortunately I doubt that a polynomial with least degree is unique in any meaningful sense. We also certainly do not have many of the nice properties like the fact that the minimal polynomial 'divides' or is part of the word of any other polynomial of which $h$ is a root. Alot of this comes from the fact that we don't have an appropriate notion of $0$ in a group. Sure we can solve for $p(h) = e$, but $p(h)q(h) \neq e$ in general and so on

I'm sure that study of these objects will yield some results, but they won't be as elementary or as powerful results from polynomials over fields.

This isn't a very good answer and I'm not versed enough in group theory to provide any facts about group polynomials. However if you still have interest in these objects I encourage you to study them. Maybe this answer and others will help you find some references.

Comment: I will look further for a day or two.   The analogy is not going to match up perfectly.  It's more about the abstract notions such as 'extension', 'minimal polynomial', the (type Y)[x] space also being a (type Y), and so on...  Grobner base theory doesn't act always analogously to single variable theory, for instance.  One thing it will share is the fact that it is algebraic in nature, and algebraic approaches are always nice.  Even if it repeats results found using another branch of group theory, it still has value because some problems immediately come in this form and not the absract other.

Comment: I should add that your definition of the group should also include the indeterminate $x^{-1}$, since groups multiplication is invertible and also so it coincides with $G \coprod \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: do you mean writing $G[x,x^{-1}]$ for the set of monomials over $G$, except when $G$ is finite?

Comment: yes, so maybe write $G(x)$? :) EDIT: I don't know why you state 'except when $G$ is finite?$

Comment: I think for economy I'll write either $G(x)$ or $G[x]$.

Comment: I've already found that degree is not the highest exponent as in field theory side, but instead the number of exponents occuring in the polynomial expression, and it satisfies $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$ which is perfectly the same.  Thank you for your help.